# How to check if string value of a field is a substring of another field in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

1.Assuming I have a collection named test and contain three documents. The structure of document would be like:

```
{
       Text: " String is string",
       Text1:  "string"
       
       
 },

{
       Text: "Good is good",
       Text1: "good"
       
       
 }
```

2. How can I write a aggregation query to find all the documents where Text contains Text1 (case insensitive)?

Comment: This is invalid JSON - you have an unfinished closure on your double quote.  Also, what is Text1?  You show a string for a value, but it is not in double quotes.

Comment: I’m using my phone to type the JSON. That’s why I can’t type correctly

Comment: I update the JSON file

Answer (score 2):

you can make use of regular expression to match the text1 in text sample code:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/d2WJO7sG1jO

```
    db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      matched: {
        $regexMatch: {
          "input": "$Text",
          "regex": "$Text1",
          options: "i"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      matched: true
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      matched: 0
    }
  }
])
```

Here we add additional field by checking if Text1 is there in Text with case insensitive. if match found then only we return the matched results. Note here we just check on self document we are not matching across the documents.